# Average Rating Trigger ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a trigger where is takes a several number of ratings from a table called FEEDBACK, and it creates an Average Rating on the MEMBER table. I want the trigger to update the average rating of each person whenever a new feedback is inserted.

**----------- These are my tables -----------**

```
 create table Member_T(
MemberID        Varchar2 (10) primary key,
MemberFirstName Varchar2 (20) NOT NULL,
MemberLastName  Varchar2 (20) NOT NULL,
MemberMidleName Varchar2 (10),
MemberEmail     Varchar2 (50) NOT NULL,
MemberPassword  Varchar2 (20) NOT NULL,
MemberAdress    Varchar2 (50) ,
MemberCity      Varchar2 (20) ,
MemberState     char     (2)  ,
MemberCountry   Varchar2 (20) ,
MemberZipCode   number   (5,0),
MemberPhone     Varchar2 (12) ,
MemberAverageRating number (3,1) check (MemberAverageRating >= 0.0 AND   MemberAverageRating <= 5.0));

create table Feedback_T(
FeedbackID            Varchar2 (10) primary key,
FeedbackMemberGiverID Varchar2 (10) references Member_T(MemberID),
MemberReceiverID      Varchar2 (10) references Member_T(MemberID),
MemberRating          number   (3,1) check (MemberRating >= 0.0 AND MemberRating <= 5.0),
MemberComment         Varchar2 (500),
MemberFeedbackDate    Date Default(sysdate));
```

**----------- This is my trigger -----------**

```
create or replace trigger updateRating
     after insert
      on Feedback_T
      for each row
Declare
     rating         Feedback_T.MemberRating%type;
     receiver       Feedback_T.MEMBERRECEIVERID%type;
     averageRating  Member_T.MemberAverageRating%type;
begin
     select AVG(MemberRating), count(MEMBERRECEIVERID)
     into rating, receiver
     from Feedback_T
     where Feedback_T.FEEDBACKID = :new.FEEDBACKID;

     update Member_T 
     set averageRating = rating / receiver
     where Member_T.MemberID = :new.MemberID;
end;
```

**----------- I get this error -----------**

```
TRIGGER UPDATERATING compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: what client are you using to compile this?

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment?  Or for a real system?  Once you correct the compilation error, you're almost certainly going to get mutating table runtime exceptions.  And it won't work in a multiuser system.  It is possible to implement this sort of thing in a real system using triggers but it is quite a bit more complex than what you've got here.

Comment: It is something that I have been working on for my self. I am trying to create my first trigger and I want to do it using data for average rating. I still do not understand where I get this compilation error. I am using ORACLE SQL Developer and I'm having a hard time finding the compiler log...

Comment: If you're trying to create your first trigger, I would strongly suggest choosing a different problem to solve using a trigger.  This is not a problem that a trigger is the right solution for.

Comment: Okay, so how can I get the average rating for a specific person using the information that I have? I understand that this is not easy but I am curious to see how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you run "show errors" from the sql prompt, you will see your errors, or compile this in SQLDeveloper, which will show you the errors.  Your problem is:

```
where Member_T.MemberID = :new.MemberID;
```

Where there is no bind variable called :new.MemberID, since MemberID is not a column in the Feedback_T table that the trigger is for.  Maybe you meant to reference FeedbackMemberGiverID or MemberReceiverID?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I cannot find how to view errors in Oracle SQL Developer.